# How to deal with user inputted logarithmic equations in Python

Tags: python, user-input, sympy, equation, logarithm

Say for example, a user inputted `ln(x)+3x+1` as a string when I prompted them for a equation. How would I evaluate/deal with this equation in Python?

I want to use the string as a real equation that I will possibly solve/differentiate at a later stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse string expressions using `sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr`, e.g.

```
import sympy
import sympy.parsing.sympy_parser 

ex = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr("ln(x) + 3*x + 1")
print(ex.diff('x'))
```

which produces `3 + 1/x`.

For more info see the 'Parsing' section of the manual at http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html .

Comment: Shorter version: use `sympify`, also abbreviated as S. For example, `ex = sympy.S("ln(x) + 3*x + 1")` has the same effect.  `parse_expr` is needed when one has to tune the parsing methods (like parsing "xy" as `x*y`, etc).